# TVEventHandler Module is not installed

Tags: react-native, android-tv

I am trying to build an application for android tv. But when use 'TVEventHandler' It show TVEventHandler Module is not installed. I also try to install TVEventHandler but it show:

Standard error:
E404
Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/TVEventHandler - Not found

Here Is my Code:

```
 _tvEventHandler: any;

  _enableTVEventHandler() {

    this._tvEventHandler = new TVEventHandler();
    this._tvEventHandler.enable(this, function (cmp, evt) {
      if (evt && evt.eventType === 'right') {
        cmp.setState({ board: cmp.state.board.move(2) });
      } else if (evt && evt.eventType === 'up') {
        cmp.setState({ board: cmp.state.board.move(1) });
      } else if (evt && evt.eventType === 'left') {
        cmp.setState({ board: cmp.state.board.move(0) });
      } else if (evt && evt.eventType === 'down') {
        cmp.setState({ board: cmp.state.board.move(3) });
      } else if (evt && evt.eventType === 'playPause') {
        cmp.restartGame();
      }
    });
  }

  _disableTVEventHandler() {

    if (this._tvEventHandler) {
      this._tvEventHandler.disable();
      delete this._tvEventHandler;
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this._enableTVEventHandler();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {

    this._disableTVEventHandler();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because TVEventHandler and other components for build android tv deleted from react native core.
So you should run this command and it's converted your react native to tv os:

`yarn add react-native@npm:react-native-tvos@latest`

And your react native version after install react-native-tvos :

[image]

Now TVEventHandler and another tv build components added to your react native if you checked `./node_modules/react_native/Libraries/components`